# Volume group not created

Tags: centos5, lvm, partition

I have a Professional XXL with 2x 1TB HDDs (1TB RAID) server from velia.net and i want to create a volume group in it but when first i create pv it's showing.

```
           [root@xen17 ~]# pvcreate /dev/sda3
              /dev/sda3: open failed: No such device or address 
              Can't open /dev/sda3 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?
```

And the output of.

```
           [root@xen17 ~]#  grep filter /etc/lvm/lvm.conf | grep -v "#"
              filter = [ "a/.*/" ]
```

sometimes it shows

```
           [root@xen17 ~]# pvcreate /dev/sda3
           Device /dev/hda1 not found (or ignored by filtering).
```

Now i am confused why this disk is behaving like that please help me in this i am struggling in this since 4 days.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `grep sda3 /proc/partitions` to see if `sda3` is actually available on your system.

If it is, then try `grep sda3 /proc/mounts` and see if the disk you are trying to use is not actually already mounted.

Note that in a XEN guest, your block devices are most likely **not** named `sda` (`cat /proc/partitions` to see what your block devices are).